# Is it possible to join these two regex expressions into one?

Tags: regex, simplify, simplification

i have the following two `regular expressions` (in order btw).

```
1. ^~/buying/(.*)\?(.*)   => foo= group 1  baa= group 2.
2. ^~/buying/(.*)         => foo= group 1  baa= nothing/empty/null/baibai
```

What's i'm trying to do is, if the url has a questionmark, then split it into two groups. Otherwise, just throw all the stuff into the first group.

the reason why the order is important for me, is that if i switch them round, the '?' regex will never get fired because the #2 expression (above) will catch all.

So .. can this be re-fixed?

NOTE: I have tried [using this website](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)** to help me debug/tweak .. but I can't figure it out.

** I have no affiliation with that site.

Comment: Is this perl? I suggest you tag it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
^~/buying/([^?]*)\??(.*)
```

`([^?]*)` - Captures the first group, which doesn't contain a question mark.
`\??` - Optional question mark.
`(.*)` - Optional second group - can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

How about just making the second part optional (untested):

```
^~/buying/([^\?]*)(?:\?(.*))?
```

The `?:` is there to prevent the optional part (the part you need plus the question mark) from capturing.

Edit: Because of greediness, you need to use either the negated character class [^\?] or make it lazy. (The negated character class is preferred because it reduces backtracking.)

Comment: I've started with something similar. It doesn't work, because `.*` captures everything right from the start, leaving the second group empty.

Comment: You'd need to add a "?" directly after the .* to make it non-greedy.

Comment: @annakata - you also need to add `$` at the end - or both groups will always be empty!

Comment: @Kobi Yes, good point. And after that, yours is a bit easier to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

also you can join like this, easier to understand.

> `^~/buying/(.*)(\?(.*))?$`

Comment: Doesn't work - see my comment to LC. You can go non-greedy and add `$` at the end, but then it isn't so easier to understand anymore :)